# Switch Statement in react-router-dom is always loading the Home route and no other route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-v4

I am trying to set up a 404 route which is why I am using the Switch component of react-router-dom. Any path that I put in will continue to the render the home route.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ExpenseDashboard from './components/ExpenseDashboard'
import AddExpensePage from './components/AddExpensePage'
import HelpPage from './components/HelpPage';
import EditPage from './components/EditPage';
import Header from './components/Header';
import NoMatch from './components/NoMatch';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={ExpenseDashboard} />
          <Route path='/create' component={AddExpensePage} />
          <Route path='/Edit' component={EditPage} />
          <Route path='/Help' component={HelpPage} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

that is my app component utilizing the switch component above. The ExpenseDashboard continues to load.

I am using `react-router-dom 4.2` and `react v16` and used `create-react-app` to make this project.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add `path="*"` to your 404 route? i.e. `<Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />`

Comment: Your code works as expected. I created a sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/x2q2jz2l3o and it is showing the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following line:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={ExpenseDashboard} />
```

Or remove only 'exact'.

Then some navigation link. See this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to='/create'> Create </Link>
        <Link to='/ExpenseDashboard'> Expense Dashboard </Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/ExpenseDashboard' component={ExpenseDashboard} />
          <Route path='/create' component={AddExpensePage} />
          <Route path='/Edit' component={EditPage} />
          <Route path='/Help' component={HelpPage} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Read More:  [On GitHub](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md)

Comment: This answer is incorrect.
The questioner's routing structure is sound.

The problem lies elsewhere.  Most likely with his url's.